# Managing different page styles' name and definition

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have two main questions:

1. How to copy a page style under a different name?
2. How to create a new page style based on an existing page style?
   For example, to add a footer to an existing page style.

Comment: Do you use the `fancyhdr` package?

Comment: `\makeatletter\let\ps@mainstlye\ps@plain\makeatother\pagestyle{mainstyle}` - is this what you are looking for (mainstyle is created from plain in the example)?

Comment: Yes, i am using `fancyhdr`.  I will try your hack.

Comment: This works, but i was also hoping to be able to reuse the copied page style when redefining the page style under the same name. Probably these were two separate questions. Can i do it anyway?

Comment: For the first question, the `fancyhdr` command `\fancypagestyle{<name>}{<hdr,ftr,etc...>}` would be what you're asking for, because the options inside the command can be equal and the `<name>` could vary as you want. For the second question, you could change the options of a fancy page style (making similar to others) but you have to keep a different name (it is obivous that LaTeX does not know which one to choose in this case).

Comment: @AndreaL. Why don't you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet to create a new style as a copy a previous one:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@mainstlye\ps@plain
\makeatother
```

The [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142180/managing-different-page-styles-name-and-definition?noredirect=1#comment321628_142180) made by [@AndreaL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/28100/andrea-l) has some useful info.